# Sharepoint 2010 workflow - test for "modified by" person in an AD group?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, active-directory

I have a work flow that checks if a new record was modified by any of a number of people. Currently written as

```
If Modified by Joe Jones
or modified by Jane Smith
or modified by Alan Green
Then Stop the workflow and log completely
```

That list is getting rather large, and I'm wondering if there's a way to check against an AD group instead. If the record is modified by someone in said group, proceed as normal.

That sounds more flexible - easier to add someone to the approved list. I could use a list that I was also using to provide permissions to the site or page as well, and there'd be one less place to change the names.

Not sure if that's allowed, and don't know the syntax if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no Condition or Action as OOTB to check if the user in a specific AD group. it will require developing an event receiver or workflow via Visual studio to achieve your goal.

**The available workarounds without code:**

1. Instead of checking the users in the AD group and try to add them to SharePoint Group and use a free CodePlex solution http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ that has `Is User a member of a SharePoint group` condition.
2. Or buy a 3rd party tool like [Vitro](https://www.virtosoftware.com/office-365/sharepoint-online-workflow).
3. Use `Call HTTP web service` and use REST as mentioned at [how to check user is a member of a group](http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/12/15/spd2013-workflow-how-to-check-user-is-member-of-group.html).

   - **Note:** `Call HTTP web service` Action is not available in SharePoint workflow 2010.